# Read & Extract "Department" of a Google Contact

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-contacts-api

Good evening,

I have a large list of emails from my company in a Google Sheet (column A) and I need to put the Departement Name of each person in column B.

How can I get the Department name related to each contact? I could not find the appropriate code online

I tried some things based on Apps Script documentation but I only get "null" values

Kind regards
Gabriel

Comment: You haven't yet provided any details. We do not know what your data in Column A looks like, what the possible department names are, what the "some things" are that you tried in Apps Script, etc. Keep in mind that we cannot see what you are seeing.

Comment: Yes, just to reiterate what Erik said. It would be very helpful to have more details and to see a sample of the data and what you have tried so far. See [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)